# How to get rid of annoying warning when I use Pandas DataFrame DROP method with condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I run this code:

```
from datetime import datetime

df_students_ages = df_students.dropna()
df_students_ages.loc[:, ['birth_year']] = df_students_ages.birthday.apply(lambda x : x.split('-')[0])

#conditional drop
df_students_ages.drop(df_students_ages[df_students_ages.birth_year > '2015'].index, inplace=True)
df_students_ages.drop(df_students_ages[df_students_ages.birth_year < '1920'].index, inplace=True)

df_students_ages.drop(columns='birth_year', inplace=True)
df_students_ages.loc[:, ['birthday']] = df_students_ages.birthday.apply(pd.to_datetime)

def from_dob_to_age(born):
    today = pd.to_datetime(datetime.now().date())
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))

df_students_ages.loc[:, ['age']] = df_students_ages.birthday.apply(lambda x: from_dob_to_age(x))

df_students_ages.sort_values('age')
```

I get this warning:

```
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:659: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self.obj[k] = np.nan
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1745: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  isetter(ilocs[0], value)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4163: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  return super().drop(
```

How to avoid getting it? What else should I put in '.loc[]' form? I have no idea how to combine it with conditional drop.

The output is neat.

[image: The output is neat]

Answer (score 0):

in

```
#conditional drop
df_students_ages.drop(df_students_ages[df_students_ages.birth_year > '2015'].index, inplace=True)
df_students_ages.drop(df_students_ages[df_students_ages.birth_year < '1920'].index, inplace=True)

df_students_ages.drop(columns='birth_year', inplace=True)
df_students_ages.loc[:, ['birthday']] = df_students_ages.birthday.apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

You may need to modify it to be something like in the following lines:

```
#conditional drop
df_students_ages = df_students_ages.drop(df_students_ages[df_students_ages.birth_year > '2015'].index, inplace=True)
df_students_ages = df_students_ages.drop(df_students_ages[df_students_ages.birth_year < '1920'].index, inplace=True)

df_students_ages = df_students_ages.drop(columns='birth_year', inplace=True)
df_students_ages = df_students_ages.loc[:, ['birthday']] = df_students_ages.birthday.apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Comment: `inplace=True` flag is used instead of equation

Comment: Thanks, for your comment, If we use the suggested lines without 'inplace=True`, will it give the same annoying messages?

Comment: Thank you for the idea, it indeed has removed a part of my warnings output, this one:

```
{...} SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: {...}
  return super().drop(
```

The above warnings remain.

Comment: which messages have left (still existed)?

Comment: It is not convenient to copy code in comments.

Comment: Under a title **updateing upon answering** at the end of your question mention to what we did and add the messages left.

Comment: Sorry, I still think it is not a good style to use extra value assignment instead of a good flag 'inplace=True '. The reason I fight with this warning is to achieve a better code quality.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer myself. The only thing I actually need to do is to copy the whole source data frame before starting to remove non-valid rows. This way I even avoided using the '.loc[]' function where I could. The final code looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

# this is what has actually changed
df_students_ages = df_students
df_students_ages.dropna(inplace=True)

# new column creation without .loc
df_students_ages['birth_year'] = df_students_ages.birthday.apply(lambda x : x.split('-')[0])
# dropping inplace
df_students_ages.drop(df_students_ages[df_students_ages.birth_year > '2015'].index, inplace=True)
df_students_ages.drop(df_students_ages[df_students_ages.birth_year < '1920'].index, inplace=True)

df_students_ages = df_students_ages.drop(columns='birth_year')
df_students_ages.birthday = df_students_ages.birthday.apply(pd.to_datetime)

def from_dob_to_age(born):
    today = pd.to_datetime(datetime.now().date())
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))

# new column creation without .loc 
df_students_ages['age'] = df_students_ages.birthday.apply(lambda x: from_dob_to_age(x))

df_students_ages.sort_values('age')
```